# Nusach Askenaz in siyum kaddish - vayatzmach purkanei?

Tags: kaddish, nusach-ashkenaz, siyum

I've noticed that the kaddish printed in most editions of the gemara and mishnayos includes ויצמח פורקניה ויקרב משיחיה (vayatzmach purkanei vikareiv meshichei), without annotations such as "nusach sefard".

Is it possible that Nusach Ashkenaz, which omits this phrase in other versions of the kaddish, includes it specifically for the kaddish said at a siyum?

Comment: The ArtScroll Gemaras include it in brackets.

Comment: @Scimonster I did notice that, but the Vilna edition of the gemara does not, and I don't know how much more Ashkenaz you can get than that.

Comment: I've heard that _kadish_ said without that phrase. Fwiw.

Comment: I went to a siyum on Ta'anit Bechorot in an Ashkenazi shul (Beth Aaron)-- they said the phrase.

Comment: Many Sefardim specifically don't say Vayatzmach... after a Siyum even though they say it generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen Nusach Ashkenaz siyum reciters say "Veyatzmach". According to [this article](https://www.ou.org/torah/tefillah/kaddish/the_five_types_of_kaddish/), it seems appropriate for everyone to say it. There are 5 types of Kaddish and the one recited at the end of a siyum is the same one recited at a burial. It is called *Kaddish Hagadol*. The article states:

> The final type of Kaddish (Kaddish Hagadol) is recited on two special occasions: when
>   making a siyum upon the completion of a tractate of Talmud or an order
>   of Mishna, and at a funeral. These two occasions are radically
>   different, but there is something in common. The theme of this Kaddish
>   is that, in the merit of Torah study, the world will be renewed,
>   including the eventual revival of the dead. Therefore, it is
>   appropriate for both a siyum (recognizing as it does the rewards of
>   Torah study) and a funeral (as it contains within it the consolation
>   that those who have passed on will someday return to us).

Comment: I do not think that the linked article is implying in any way anything about "Veyatzmach".  The entire statement that you quote above applies to Kaddish in general as the theme of Kaddish is about renewal; Kaddish says nothing about the dead.  As further evidence, Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim like Artscroll and Koren do not have "Veyatzmach" as part of the Kaddish at a funeral.

Answer (score 2):

I have been to many (Nusach Ashkenaz) siyums, and have never heard the person say "VaYitzmach..."  The siyums that I have been to include by alumnus of YU, Chofetz Chayim, and Lakewood.  All are predominantly Nusach Ashkenaz.

I wonder if it is because you are in Eretz Yisrael where Nusach Sefarad is common that you have seen this written.

The Koren Talmud Bavli explicitly said that it is only said for Nusach Sefarad.

Comment: Please consider moving the observation to the comments section as it comprises unsourced (albeit somewhat compelling) information. (The reference to the Koren Talmud should be fine)

Answer (score 1):

The new Oz Vehadar gemorahs put these words in brackets.